# NodeJS Express Mongoose how to make a get query with parameteres

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm writing a node js method which I want to find vlaues which match the `imei.name` parameter passed in, and the test field is empty.

This is the method which I tried to use:

```
router.get('/gettdata/', (req, res, next) => {

    let aa=req.query.imei;
    console.log(aa);
    Post.findOne( {imei:{"imei.name":req.body},
  test:{$exists:false}
  }


    )
      .then((posts) => {
        res.json(posts);
        console.log(posts);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  });
```

it returns an empty field despite it exists when I use only

```
Post.findOne( {"imei.name":req.body})
```

it works and when I use only

```
Post.findOne( 
  test:{$exists:false}
 )
```

it works but the problem is using them two in one time

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb7f90fb88d8d4d94184333"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "bokhhjbr",
                "modele" : "5486"
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eb7fb9cb88d8d4d94184334"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "865566048694354",
                "modele" : "CPH1803"
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5eba73395fd8dd073065efdf"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "bok55555555555hjbr",
                "modele" : "5486"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-12T09:58:17.203Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-05-12T09:58:17.203Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed0f93c0c93ec1c785358ab"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "865566048694354"
        },
        "test" : {
                "tactileState" : "1",
                "pixelState" : "1",
                "greyState" : "1"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-29T11:59:56.441Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-05-29T11:59:56.441Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed0f9420c93ec1c785358ac"),
        "imei" : {
                "name" : "865566048694354"
        },
        "test" : {
                "tactileState" : "1",
                "pixelState" : "1",
                "greyState" : "1"
        },
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-29T12:00:02.040Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-05-29T12:00:02.040Z"),
        "__v" : 0
}
```

and that's my database shown in cmd.

I need some help - thank you

Comment: try using `req.body`, it gives an array...

Comment: the same probleme

Comment: Ok, can you try redefining your route as `/getdata` and then in your request your url should look like `/getdata?imei=sdfasdfadas`...Also, you can use `req.param("imei")` if you don't know where the value might be, but `req.query.imei` is all you'd need.

Comment: you need to use findOne() [Doc here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne)

Comment: i don't understand what you mean butt i updated the question if you can check it

Answer (score 0):

Use the `req.params`

```
router.get('/gettdata/:imei', (req, res, next) => {

   console.log(req.params.imei);


})
```

You pass the parameters like this:

http://url.com/gettdata/test

You will see `test` in the console.

```
/gettdata/:imei/:parameter2/:parameter3
```

Then you pass it like this

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the name of the data you passed to the req body. If "imei" is the name of the data you passed to the body, do this;

```
Post.findOne({"imei.name":req.body.imei})
```